# hera to odin, on windows surface 6 dual boot

Tags: boot, microsoft-windows

I would like to erase hera and install odin on top of it. I cannot use the erase and install option as it seems to erase all partitions on the disk and would erase windows data.

When using custom install, I need to choose a boot partition. I do not remember having done this for installing hera.
I can see there is already an efi partition of 260mb (first partition on disk).

Do I need to use and select this already existing partition for boot? or create a new one of 260mb?

then I would create paritions for root home and swap as seems it would easier further upgrade or reinstall process in future. I would have 20gb for root, 60gb for home and 8gb for swap, all in ext4

Answer (score 0):

from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

> If your disk already contains an ESP (eg if your computer had Windows
> 8 preinstalled), it can be used for Ubuntu too. Do not format it. It
> is strongly recommended to have only 1 ESP per disk.

So I will try to use the existing one and hope its all good